# Using this pointer to write object to binary file in c++

Tags: c++, object, file-handling, ostream, this-pointer

```
void Employee::store_data(string filename) {
    fstream file;
    file.open(filename,ios::app | ios::binary);
    if (file) {
        file.write((char*)&this,sizeof(this));
        file.close();
    }
    else cout<<"\n Error in Opening the file!";

}
```

this is what i tried.
I want to store the current object of employee class to a file in binary mode.
but i get this this

```
error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand
     file.write((char*)&this,sizeof(this));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` isn't an actual variable, so you can't take its address. But it already *is* a pointer, so you don't need to. It also has size of a pointer, so your `sizeof` is wrong. And then in C++ you should not use C-style casts. So fixing these 3 things, your line becomes

```
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this), sizeof(*this));
```

That should compile.

**However**, note that if Employee contains anything complex, such as `std::string` member variables, pointer member variables, virtual methods, constructor / destructor etc, you can't read the data back. That write doesn't in that case write everything, or writes wrong runtime values, and you get garbage back. You enter the dreaded *Undefined Behavior* territory, anything can happen (including things apparently working when you test it).

Comment: so what shoud i do to avoid garbage values?

Answer (score 1):

The language does not allow use of `&this` as an expression since (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.this#1)

> the keyword `this` is a prvalue expression

You can use the `addressof` (`&`) operator only on lvalue expressions.

More importantly, you need to use

```
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(this), sizeof(*this));
```

to save the object.